# how to get ordered result set while using in keyword in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run the below query in order to get ordered data from category_child table and accordingly from the category table.
select * from category where id in (select child_id from category_child where category_id=1 order by sequence);

It's like

```
select * from category where id in (2,3,4);
```

and

```
select * from category where id in (3,2,4);
```

are giving me the same result.
Is there any way I can get the result in the same order.

category and category_child tables are:

```
-- Table structure for table `category`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `category`;<br/>
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;<br/>
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;<br/>
CREATE TABLE `category` (<br/>
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,<br/>
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,  <br/>
  `description` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,<br/>
  `image_url` VARCHAR(250),<br/>
  `created_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '2014-11-06 00:00:00',<br/>
  `updated_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  <br/>
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)<br/>
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;<br/>
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;<br/>

--
-- Table structure for table `category_child`<br/>
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `category_child`;<br/>
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;<br/>
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;<br/>
CREATE TABLE `category_child` (<br/>
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,<br/>
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,<br/>
  `child_id` int(11) NOT NULL,<br/>
  `child_type` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,<br/>
  `sequence` int(4) NOT NULL,<br/>
  `created_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '2014-11-06 00:00:00',<br/>
  `updated_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  <br/>
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)<br/>
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;<br/>
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;<br/>
```

Comment: please create a fiddle on http://sqlfiddle.com with some sample data and provide the expected output to your question.

Comment: Why not just use `ORDER BY`?

Comment: As far as I know. ORDER BY would solve his problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following query

```
select c.* 
from category c, category_child cc 
where cc.category_id=1 and c.id=cc.child_id 
order by cc.sequence;
```

will work, just a little change in condition in the answer given by Nir-Z and removing join.

Comment: This is exactly what Nir-Z answered last week (the only difference is the outdated implicit join in the where clause)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: yeah it will work if he changes the condition from cc.id=c.category_id to c.id = cc.child_id :). but yeah his approach was completely fine :).

Answer (score 1):

Why not doing

```
Select c.* 
from category c 
join category_child cc on cc.id=c.category_id 
where cc.category_id=1 
order by cc.sequence
```

Comment: category_id in category_child table is referencing id in category table. it and it should be '...join category_child cc on c.id=cc.category_id....' sorry but query didn't work for me. It is returning only first row from category table.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get them ordered by `category_child.sequence`, then they will be returned in whatever order the utilized index returns the `category` results.

So @Nir-Z's answer will get you results sorted by the order of `category_child.sequence`, but if there were multiple indexes on `category` you could get differing results.

The only way to enforce consistent results every time would be to provide an order for `category` as well.

```
Select c.* 
from category c 
join category_child cc on cc.category_id=c.id 
where cc.category_id=1 
order by cc.sequence, c.name
```

`c.name` can be any of the fields from `category`.

Comment: category_id in category_child table is referencing id in category table. it and it should be '...join category_child cc on c.id=cc.category_id....' sorry but query didn't work for me. It is returning only first row category table.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the result's order with the `where` clause (at least not deterministically). Instead, you should just add an explicit `order by` clause:

```
select * from category where id in (2,3,4) order by id;

select * from category where id in (3,2,4) order by id;
```